# Is the impulse response of a real system is always a real function?

Tags: signal-processing, radar

As stated in the title, is the impulse response of a real system is always a real function? Can it ever be complex/analytic, etc.? I'm more interested in terms of radar systems. Any info would be helpful.

Comment: When you say a "real system" do you mean a system whose inputs and outputs can be expressed as real numbers, or do you mean a system that exists in reality?

Comment: Well, the latter implies the former, if you're being strict about keeping to a framework where inphase and quadrature signals are real-valued.

Comment: This might be useful ..https://www.keysight.com/ca/en/assets/7018-02435/white-papers/5990-5266.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this answer:

1. In the time domain, if a real system is defined as one where the impulse response is entirely real (i.e., no complex component) and the input is real, then mathematically, the output signal is entirely real (you're just convolving two real functions, the output is real).
2. Things are more complicated in the frequency domain thanks to causality:
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations . An entirely real time domain impulse function (and signal) can be complex in the frequency domain. Then, because of causality, the real and complex components of the impulse response are themselves related to each other. The good news is that if you know one, you can calculate the other using the above linked Kramers-Kronig relations.

Answer (score 0):

It will always be a real function, yes.

If the impulse response is a sine or a cosine function you may represent it as a complex exponential function just for simplifying subsequent calculations.

At the very end of the calculations you have to get back to the real function.

Example:

cos(t - 2) = Re(exp(i*(t - 2)))

where i = sqrt(-1)